# C# - Nunit - nunit3-console not picking the mentioned class file in the where filter

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

While running an Nunit project with the .csproj extension through Nunit3-console, the two tests are correctly picked correctly.

```
nunit3-console.exe SeleniumCHash.csproj
```

But, when I try to filter out one of the tests by selecting the class file to be executed, the tests are not getting picked up.

```
nunit3-console.exe --where "class =~ 'SeleniumCHash: FirstTest'" SeleniumCHash.csproj
```

The following is my Class File.

```
namespace SeleniumCHash
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FirstTest : TestBaseClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void LoginCheck()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using suggests you have a class named "SeleniumCHash: FirstTest". Of course, that's impossible. So when no test is found, no tests are run.

You don't provide your code, but I'm guessing it's something like

```
namespace Some.Thing
{
    public class SeleniumCHash
    {
        [Test]
        public void FirstTest() { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

You could run FirstTest using any of the options

```
--where "class == Some.Thing.SeleniumCHash && method == FirstTest"
--test Some.Thing.SeleinumCHash.FirstTest
--where "test == Some.Thing.SeleniumCHash.FirstTest"
--where "test =~ FirstTest"
```

The last one, of course, will only work if there are no other tests that match "FirstTest". If there are, then all of them will run.

Note that `class` and `method` refer to the C# elements whereas `test` refers to the full name of the test, which **usually** contain those elements but which also may be modified by the user writing the test code.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie. But, what would be the syntax if I want to run all the tests in  class file. Sorry for missing the class file structure earlier. I've added the same in the question now.

Comment: Found it myself. **nunit3-console.exe --where "class = SeleniumCHash.FirstTest" SeleniumCHash.csproj**...Thanks for leading me in the right path. Accepting your answer.